# How do I use compiled stylesheets in saxon/c?

Tags: c++, xml, xslt, saxon

I downloaded the latest beta release of Saxon/C but I can't quite figure out how to use the compile stylesheet functionality. There's a function in the class XsltProcessor.h :-

```
void compile(const char* stylesheet);
```

that claims to compile a stylesheet but I can't see anything that would apply this compiled stylesheet to an actual source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile method allows you to supply the stylesheet as a string representation which is then compiled and cached internally for later use.

To execute the stylesheet call the method xslt->xsltApplyStylesheet("sample.xml", NULL) but supply NULL in the argument  where you would pass the file name.

You could also supply the source document as a string using the methods parseXmlString and setSourceValue. In the xsltApplyStylesheet you pass NULL for the source file argument.

We will make the usability better in next release.

Comment: so if i set both source and stylesheet parameters, then calling it with xsltApplyStylesheet(NULL, NULL) will run the pre-compiled stylesheet on the pre-set source?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [sample code here](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/index.html)? It uses `XsltProcessor.xsltApplyStylesheet()`, which is documented [here](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/classXsltProcessor.html#a30811fa2736f9f02ea888f442928b708).

The sample code seems to have a typo in that it says `test->xsltApplyStylesheet()` when it means `xslt->xsltApplyStylesheet()`.

I'm not sure what the `compile()` method does with its results, or how to use them.